# Java generate PDF from RTF

Tags: java, pdf, rtf

I want to generate PDF file from RTF file. 
I have tried following.

1. Itext
   It's already outdated and new version doesn't support rtf.
2. JDocConverter
   It uses OpenOffice on the background. it is working fine, there is only one problem. Open office doesn't support drawing object in RTF.

Any other possible and reliable solutions?

Note: It would be fine don't use any commercial software.

Comment: Any reason you cannot script Office to open the file and print to a PDF-printer?

Comment: In java? No idea how to do that.

Comment: using Office scripting tools.  Only use Java to launch those.

Comment: but it requires Microsoft Office. And I have no information that microsoft office is able print to pdf

Comment: Office gives the best result.  You can install a third party printer which does not print to a physical printer, but a PDF file.  Also modern versions of office can install a "print to PDF" plugin.

Comment: Ok but I am still missing something. How can I call Ms office from java code?

Comment: but any way Ms Office is not for free

Comment: please edit your question to include all requirements.

Comment: do you know how to open document with word viewer from powershell?

Comment: no, but if you want 100% compatibility with Office, you need Office to do it.  Consider asking a new question about how to script Office to print to a given printer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has native convert RTF to PDF using command line, however it will to a degree be limited, so it will use direct convert text and images, but it will depend on rtf syntax as to which drawn objects are supported. WORD ART drawing objects need MS Word to print

[image]

The output looks reasonable but **here is the source in MSWord** where the art was clearly not handled by the non-word printout.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You may try [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) to convert RTF file to PDF format. You can [load a file in RTF format into Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/load-or-create-a-document.html) and then [save it to PDF format](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/save-a-document.html). Please note that while loading specify RTF as LoadFormat value and pass PDF as SaveFormat value while saving the document. This doesn't require OpenOffice or any other software to be installed for the conversion to work.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Ok it sound nice but it is not for free

Answer (score -2):

Under Windows you could print to [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp).  This freeware uses Ghostscript as a back end.

Answer (score -3):

Best way to do it is use MS Office. And Ms Office is able to save file in PDF format (you need install some addons I think).